# Android "wrong password or username " message box display error

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on an activity that has username and password. I used the **AlertDialog.Builder** in the **else** part to show the message of "wrong password or username". I am not connecting it with any database just for the test purpose using strings for password and username to compare the values of editText fields with, in the **if** condition and if match it takes the user to a new screen name **"NewMenu"**. My problem is that when the login activity starts (the app runs), it shows first of all the message, that is the **else** part, I want to show this message after the submit button has been clicked and the the password or username was wrong. Here is the code

```
public class Login extends Activity{


    private String pass=new String();
    private String nam=new String();
    private Button log;
    private View textreg;
    private EditText text1;
    private EditText text2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        textreg=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRegister);
        log=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
        text1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtuname);
        text2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);



              //IF NOT REGISTERED USERS//
////A textview when clicked takes user to registeration page/////

        textreg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.Register"));
                    }
                });


         //                                                        //
        // IF PASSWORD AND USERNAME CORRECT, GOTO NewMenu Activity //
       //                                                        //

        pass="12345";
        nam="12345";

        if(text1.getText().toString().equals(nam) && text2.getText().toString().equals(pass) ){


            log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                        public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.NewMenu"));
                        }
                    });

        }

            else{
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();

            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: dlgAlert.create().show(); should come after setPositiveButton. Do reply what problem you are facing after that edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is not ok. onCreate() is called when your Activity is created, so it will check  username and password at each creation. As you never set the text fields, their values are never OK at the first launch, so you ALWAYS show the error dialog at the first launch. You should make something like this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // 1. Call super() and init fields

    String pass="12345";
    String nam="12345";

    // 2. Set the onClickListener
    textreg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.Register"));
        }
    });

    // 3. Set the onClickListener for the Login button
    log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // 4. Check if fields are null
            if(text1.getText() != null && text2.getText() != null) {

                // 4.a check if username and password are OK
                if(text1.getText().toString().equals(nam) && 
                    text2.getText().toString().equals(pass) )
                {    
                    // Not null and OK, launch the activity            
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.NewMenu"));
                } else {
                    // Username or password false, display and an error
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                    dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                    dlgAlert.create().show();

                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                // The fields are not filled.
                // Display an error message like "Please enter username/password
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can add `dialog.dismiss();` inside onClick.

Answer (score 1):

You should write this alertview code in click event.

```
log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(text1.getText().toString().equals(nam) && text2.getText().toString().equals(pass) )
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();

            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.NewMenu"));
        }
    }
});

}
```

you don't need to check username n pass in oncreate method.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    private String pass = new String();
    private String nam = new String();
    private Button log;
    private View textreg;
    private EditText text1;
    private EditText text2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        textreg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRegister);
        log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtuname);
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);

        // IF NOT REGISTERED USERS//
        // //A textview when clicked takes user to registeration page/////

        textreg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.Register"));
            }
        });

        // //
        // IF PASSWORD AND USERNAME CORRECT, GOTO NewMenu Activity //
        // //

        pass = "12345";
        nam = "12345";

        log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (text1.getText().toString().equals(nam)
                        && text2.getText().toString().equals(pass)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.DRMS.NewMenu"));
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getApplicationContext());

                    dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                    dlgAlert.create().show();

                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your if/else condition inside the onClick method.That will ensure it is only executed after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your alert dialog code will go in on the onclick of the registration button